# How to hash passwords with an Android client to PHP server?

Tags: php, android, json, ssl, hash

I am relatively new to programming and I'm working on a little application. The app is running on an android device and needs user based information from my PHP web server.

My plan is to use JSON for the communication between the phone and the server so the Phone should send the user data and password via get or post to the web server and receive JSON data back.

The question is now, how can I make this connection save? It is a hobby project so I don't want to invest to much in SSL certificates.

Is there some RSA Libary or some good hash function that I can use for this communication?

How safe is the PHP-based hash function: [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) and is there something that it can communicate with in Java?

The data is probably not so critical and the application is just for training for me. However, because it is user related data it should not be to easily to break.

Comment: Yes, if you aren't willing to use real SSL certs, use bcrypt on the Android device, which is basically what `password_hash()` uses. Make sure you salt it too - [Java will have something for this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+bcrypt+salt).

Comment: I thought certs were pretty cheap these days though - [this one starts at 5.69 USD](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/domain-validation.aspx) per year. That might save you some hassle - you can just do (more thorough) hashing on the server.

Comment: a cool thank you, i will check for bcrypt, if to much work or when I know some more people that will use the app. Than maybe I will take SSL.

Comment: If you simply hash the password client-side and send the hash over, then the hash is now the password. Anyone listening to the conversation can simply intercept and replay the authentication and be granted access. Either use SSL, or an authentication scheme like CRAM or DIGEST that prevents the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in a [zero-knowledge scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_password_proof).
There's a javascript/php example at https://github.com/RuslanZavacky/srp-6a-demo